# React <div id="root"></div> breaking the design, How can I avoid this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am implementing a template with reactjs, but the footer gets to break, it should be at the bottom.

The main `<div id="root"></div>` causing this. Can anyone know how to avoid it?

[image]

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * Import Custom Component
 */
import MainLayout from "./components/layout/MainLayout";
import ErrorPage from "./components/pages/errors/ErrorPage";

/**
 * Import the Pages Here
 */
import Home from "./components/pages/app/Home";

class App extends Component{

    constructor() {
      super();
      console.log("Application Started");
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <MainLayout path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route component={ErrorPage}></Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </>
      );
    };
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What does your code look like? How can we help you if you don't post any code? That's like asking a car mechanic to tell you what's wrong with your car without showing him the car.

Comment: Basic React render method, I convert the template html to jsx and put in render() in App.js. Nothing is there.

Comment: Copy and paste your code here and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

It’s because you are not setting your paths correctly, the routing paths should look like this. Sorry I’m on mobile. Try this

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react- 
router-dom;

<Switch>
<Route exact path=“/” component={MainLayout} />
<Route path=“*” component={ErrorPage} />
</Switch>
```

The * path serves as a catch all route for any path that is not expressed

Without having your full code it’s hard to tell. Another issue could be colliding divs inside MainLayout and ErrorPage.

Also if there is no content. I would re-iterate what the other answer says. Use css positioning

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Its design issue nothing wrong with functional, If I remove the route issue still persist.

Comment: It seems like on your page that’s a footer. Most of the time content will push it down. I would double check your index.html to see if there is a double #root element as well. It’s also possible that the divs wrapping your elements in your other pages are colliding with each other!

Answer (score 1):

Just make the `<body>` tag your root, like so:

```
<body id="root">
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try this,

```
position: 'absolute',
bottom: 0,
```